# Question about sentence in application note: "incremented modulo-256". Request explanation and clarification

Tags: wireless, 802.15.4

Context: I am reading an application note for a UWB transceiver. In it they are describing the typical message frame format, in accordance with IEEE rules. There is some wording that is confusing me and I am unsure whether I need to implement anything on the host controller, in accordance with this information.

In [this application note (pg. 6 of 15)](https://www.decawave.com/sites/default/files/aps013_dw1000_and_two_way_ranging_v2.2.pdf)

It says

> The sequence number octet is **incremented modulo-256** for every frame sent, as per IEEE rules. The
>   source and destination addresses are either 64-bit numbers programmed uniquely into each unit
>   (during manufacture) or 16-bit addresses temporarily assigned. The 2-octet FCS is a CRC frame
>   check sequence following the IEEE standard, (this can be generated automatically by the DW1000 IC
>   and appended to the transmitted message)

In the [IEEE standard (802.15.4-2011) (pg. 59)](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~liue/teaching/comm_standards/2015S_zigbee/802.15.4-2011.pdf)

It states:

> **5.2.1.2 Sequence Number field**
>
> The Sequence Number field specifies the **sequence identifier for the frame**.
>       For a beacon frame, the Sequence Number field shall specify a BSN. For a 
>       data, acknowledgment, or MAC
>       command frame, the Sequence Number field shall specify a DSN that is used to 
>       match an acknowledgment
>       frame to the data or MAC command frame.

I understand the principles of modulo arithmetic and I understand (and please correct me if this is wrong) that the *sequence number* refers to a frame and its order within a greater sequence of frames. However, the wording "increments by modulo-256" has thrown me a little.

Does it mean that it will bit shift a single bit, within an octet, once every time a frame is sent until a pre-defined number of frames have been sent? Do I need to process this to piece the greater sequence together?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *To 255 thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be 255. ...*

Comment: thou shalt not count to 254 or 256 lest thou stop at 255... 257 is RIGHT OUT...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just means that the number is incremented. But when it reaches the value 255 the next value will be 0.

Thus the sequence will be:
0, 1, 2, 3, .... 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 0, 1, 2, ...

You will get this behavior if you use an uint8_t ( `#include <stdint.h>`) and increment it:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t sequence_number=0;
...
   sequence_number++;
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much for this answer. Is this something that I need to then process in order, or is this something that would be handled by the radio itself for radio purposes only?

Comment: The number is used to see if there where missing packets/frames. (I don't know what UWB uses) You expect to see the next number. If you see an increase of 2 or 3 you know some packets/frames have been lost. I have no idea what level of processing your radio does.

Comment: Definitely, I'll look through the rm and ds to learn more. Thanks again!

Comment: `s/stdin\./stdint\./`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Oldfart said, it means this number is maintained in a 8 bit counter.  If you interpret the value of a 8 bit counter as normal unsigned binary, then you get modulo 256 automatically.  8 bits can be 0000 0000 to 1111 1111 (= 255 decimal).  Incrementing 1111 1111 yields 1 0000 0000.  However, the counter can't store the resulting 1 bit since it's off the end.  Only the low 8 bits of the binary value are maintained, which roll over to 0000 0000.

So while modulo-256 might seem like a strange thing, it's actually fairly common as it's the result of representing a unsigned value in a 8-bit byte.

Comment: Of course, thank you. Yes after spending a short time digesting this information, it makes quite a lot of sense to calculate a value of this nature from modulo-256.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what exactly do you think is wrong?